# NSObjectInaccessibleException when sending NSManagedObject as object with NSNotification

Tags: cocoa, core-data

I'm getting an NSObjectInaccessibleException when sending NSManagedObject as object with NSNotification. The notification is sent on the same thread as where the NSManagedObjectContext lives. It does not happen at all times and I can't track down what the exception causes.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could it be that you are accidentally using a deleted object in the notification?

Comment: Yes, this appeared to be the case! Thanks.